# tomcat in eclipse - startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-indigo

When i start tomcat and check in the browser i get the welcome page.But when i start tomcat through eclipse indigo i get the 404 error with the following message in the console :

I have tried clean, publish, restart server.

```
 Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in       production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java   \jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;\\sap.corp\sysvol\sap.corp\Policies\{90387E88-9625-4273-B47E-6F3AFFFA2313}\Machine\Scripts\Startup;%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin";%SystemRoot%\system32\WBEM;C:\Users\I068849\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PrajnaaWebClient' did not find a matching property.
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 877 ms
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CacheControlFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.ui5.resource.CacheControlFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
    Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/PrajnaaWebClient] startup failed due to previous errors
    Mar 21, 2012 10:46:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
    Mar 21, 2012 10:46:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Mar 21, 2012 10:46:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 530 ms
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.ui5.resource.CacheControlFilter` Check which jar own this class and make sure that jar is reference in your project classpath in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven build project make sure that you have added M2_REPO variable with value "Path_Upto_MavenRepo" .